# jquery append() not working on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, append

Consider the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Default item</li>
    <li>Default item</li>
</ul>
<button>Append</button>
```

and the jQuery code

```
$('button').live('click', function(){  //This action is done by an external script.
    $('ul').append('<li>Added item</li>'); 
});

$('ul li').append('<b> x</b>'); // This action is done by me
```

The thing is, I need to append the "x" mark to all newly added elements to the dom.

In this case only default elements are appended with the "x" mark.

Newly added elements are not appended by "x".

I am sure the work will be simple, but cant get it right !!

Live example - http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/LxJ6f/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is running right away, and so of course it only has access to the elements that already exist. The code adding new list items is running later, when the user clicks something. You'll have to hook into that process as well.

One way is to hook the same event they are, and run your code from the event handler. Be sure to hook the event **after** they do.

Their code:

```
$('button').live('click', function(){
    $('ul').append('<li>Added item</li>');
});
```

Your code (**after** theirs):

```
$('button').live('click', markButtons);

markButtons();

function markButtons() {
    $('ul li:not(.marked)')
        .addClass("marked")
        .append('<b> x</b>');
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxJ6f/2/)

The reason I said your code needs to do its hookup *after* their code is that jQuery guarantees the order of the calls to event handlers: When the event occurs, the handlers are called in the order in which they were attached. By attaching your handler after they attach theirs, you guarantee that your handler is called after theirs has done its thing.

If you're worried about the order getting mixed up, you could always delay your code slightly:

```
$('button').live('click', function() {
    setTimeout(markButtons, 0);
});
```

That way, your code is guaranteed to run after all of the event handlers hooked to the `click` have been run.

Answer (score 2):

You have to repeat the "x" code in the event handler:

```
$('button').live('click', function(){  //This action is done by an external script.
    $('ul').append(
      $('<li>Added item</li>').append('<b>x</b>')
    ); 
});
```

Of course you could also just put the bolded "x" right in the `<li>` when you append it ...

*edit* If you can't change the click handler, then the only thing you can do is either poll the DOM, or else try something like what @T.J. Crowder suggests (which I think should work just fine).

Comment: but the "click" action is not done my me, it is done by an external script which i cannot edit. just i need to add the "x" mark to all newly appended elements..

Comment: OK I'll edit the answer with what I think to be the only way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it in the initial append?

```
$('button').live('click', function(){  //This action is done by an external script.
    $('ul').append('<li>Added item<b> x</b></li>'); 
});
```

---

Since it sounds like you don't have access to the script that is doing the append, you could bind your own handler.

```
$('button').live('click', function(){  //This action is done by an external script.
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('ul li:not(li:has(b))').append('<b> x</b>'); 
    }, 10);
});
```

This will select `li` elements that do not currently have a nested `b` element, and it will append one.

I placed it in a `setTimeout` since you may not be able to guarantee the order of execution of the handlers.

If you prefer valid CSS selectors, do this instead:

```
$('ul li').not($('li b').closest('li')).append('<b> x</b>');
```

or this:

```
$('ul li').not(function() { return $(this).find('b').length; }).append('<b> x</b>');
```

---

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xQhsP/)** showing the two separate handlers.

Comment: actually, another script (i am not the author) appends the list item. My job is to added the "x" mark ..

Comment: thanks for trying, but I cant change the "click" block.. (mentioned in the comment) so i cant add the "settimeout" inside the click block !!

Comment: @AakashChakravarthy: Like my answer says, you bind your own. This is not changing the original. This is binding a new separate one in addition to the original.

Comment: @AakashChakravarthy: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xQhsP/) that shows the two separate handlers.