# Dynamically created HTML table immediately disappears using Flask and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Flask ([Flask API link](http://flask.pocoo.org/)) to create a very simple website that takes an 'order_id' and uses a MySQL database ([MYSQL - Python API link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/8.0.html)) in the background to finally return the associated items for that order_id in a table.

It all works well, except that the table only flashes for a second the moment I submit the order_id. It works every time I submit, but the table just won't stay.

My Python (Flask) code:

```
@app.route('/fetch_order', methods=['POST'])
def fetch_order():
    order_id    = request.form.get('order_id')
    order       = connect_db.fetch_order_json(order_id)
    order       = json.dumps(order)
    return order

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5440)
```

My JS / jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $("#order_id").submit( function() { 
        var order_id    = $('#order_id :text').val(); 
        var dataString  = 'order_id=' + encodeURIComponent(order_id);
        var body_rows   = [];
        var html        = '<tr>';

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: dataString,
                url : "/fetch_order",

                success: function(json) {
                data = JSON.parse(json);

                if (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, data_list) {
                        data_dict = JSON.parse(data_list);
                        headers = Object.keys(data_dict);
                        body_rows += '<tr>';

                        $.each(data_dict, function (ignore, value) {
                            body_rows += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
                        });
                    body_rows += '</tr>'
                    });

                    $.each(headers, function (index, header) {
                        html += '<th>' + header + '</th>';
                    });

                    html += '</tr>';
                    html += body_rows;

                    // --> working but only for a second?!
                    $('#orders_table').append(html);
                }; },
                error: ...
```

My html:

```
<div>
    <form id="order_id" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="text" name="order_id" autofocus><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <table id="orders_table">
    </table>
</div>
```

The answers to the following questions didn't help me (or I just didn't understand them well enough):

- [.show() method is not working like it is supposed to in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565941/show-method-is-not-working-like-it-is-supposed-to-in-jquery)
- [Show hide divs with addClass removeClass works, but just for a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335015/show-hide-divs-with-addclass-removeclass-works-but-just-for-a-second)
- [jquery append() not working on dynamically added elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376414/jquery-append-not-working-on-dynamically-added-elements)
- [DropDown Menu won't show for more than a second..not working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140207/dropdown-menu-wont-show-for-more-than-a-second-not-working)
- [Populate html table on jQuery success event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048922/populate-html-table-on-jquery-success-event)
- [jQuery AJAX each loop using append and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366750/jquery-ajax-each-loop-using-append-and-html)

My gut tells me it has to do with the `($.each())` loops but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any push into the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

- tried to reduce complexity by hardcoding the headers in html to no avail
- tried to rewrite jQuery to JS in case it's a jQuery thing, but it looks like it's not
- tried moving around `$('#orders_table').append(table_html);`, adding .show(), plugging it into ajaxComplete() instead, .. all to no avail

Would really love some help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after having refactored, re-written, and lost my sanity over this, the issue was a lot less complex than I thought. Turns out html `form` submissions reload the page by default.

All I had to do was to add `return false` at the end of my jQuery function that processes order_id and generates the html.. Head -> Table!
Thanks for confirming goes to
[Don't reload webpage after flask ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840526/dont-reload-webpage-after-flask-ajax-request)

Thanks to this rather silly troubleshooting madness, I learnt a lot about (almost unrelated) callbacks and the new `async/await` possibilities. For those who are interested, this post is golden:
[jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)